# Where can I find information on added subtrees?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-subtree

I have been looking at git subtree's for a project where in there would be multiple developers, multiple repositories in action. I was using sourcetree and I was able to add subtrees to my working copy from other repositories and able to push these changes to the remote copy. Everything is working fine at my end, I am able to see subtree's listed in sourcetree, selectively push updates to subtrees, get updates from it etc.

The main problem is when another developer checks out the main working copy from the remote with all the subtree's rigged up as directories they are not able to see the subtree information anywhere. I mean sourcetree does not show up the subtree's that were added in my system and the whole project is shown as one huge repository and not as one repository with multiple subtree's. Where did the subtree information go??

**Is git subtrees local only or Am I missing something big on git subtrees?**

I also tried adding subtree's with terminal instead of sourcetree but even then I was not able to see the subtree information anywhere.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope I did not find a solution yet but I had a work around.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the workaround?

Comment: I wrote a script that all user will have to run for cloning remote repositories. That script will in turn setup the git subtree setup on the local machine. It worked like a charm but we did not end up using git subtrees. I wish it helps you in someway. Sorry for the delay in reply though!!

Answer (score 0):

Git subtree creates "regular" commits from the remote repositories into the target repository. It does add some metadata to the commit message... and that's [used internally](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh#L302-L344) for subsequent `pull` commands.

```
git-subtree-dir: example/foo
git-subtree-split: 0b3d928dce8262dedfc2f83b9aeb59a94e4f0ae4
```

There is currently no "subtree list" command, although, someone did patch git-subtree.sh and apparently pushed that patch to the Git mailing list (although, I cannot find status on that patch).

[image]

https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/the-power-of-git-subtree/